# Npgsql does not commit transaction after failed command

Tags: .net, sql, postgresql, transactions, npgsql

I'm using Npgsql 2.0.11 under .NET 4.0 to modify a PostgreSQL 9.0 database. The program makes many modifications to the database, all within a single transaction.

Just before committing, I run SELECT statement, which sometimes fails (eg. with a timeout). I swallow the exception and go ahead and commit the transaction anyway. There is no error, so it appears as if everything worked, but in actual fact the database was not modified at all!

My guess is that the failed SELECT rolled back the entire transaction. Can I either prevent this (ie. have the transaction still committed) or at least detect this situation and throw an exception, so the user knows the commit failed?

I know that in this specific case I could just move the SELECT outside the transaction, but I'm more concerned about solving this for the general case. Having a commit not commit is a pretty serious problem and I want to make sure it doesn't go undetected.

Comment: If an error happens the transaction is rolled back and AFAIK (I use another ADO.NET provider - not sure this applies to Npgsql though) the connection shows "InTransaction == false" after this happens... so the called commit would just be on an "empty transaction"...

Comment: There is no `InTransaction` that I can see in Npgsql. What provider do you use?

Comment: I use the one from Devart (commercial)... the method InTransaction is something in my code... which is based on an implementation of `TransactionStateChanged` event of the Connection object...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know nothing about Npgsql, but I can speak to the behavior of PostgreSQL. When any error occurs within a PostgreSQL transaction, the transaction is marked *invalid* until it is closed. (Their term is "aborted", which I think is misleading.) Furthermore, and this is IMHO insane, if you `COMMIT` an invalid transaction, it "succeeds" but has the same effect as `ROLLBACK`. You can observe this in the `psql` REPL; it will print `ROLLBACK` in response to your `COMMIT` command, but it won't signal an error.

You can create a `SAVEPOINT` right before your final `SELECT`. If it fails, then `ROLLBACK` to the savepoint name; that will get you out of the invalid state and allow you to commit the previous part of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, +1. Without really thinking about it, I was expecting PostgreSQL to give me the same behaviour as I would get with a SAVEPOINT automatically, ie. if any given statement failed I expected the state of the database to be the same as before that statement and to be allowed to execute further commands. I've implemented the SAVEPOINT/ROLLBACK mechanism in another case, though in this case I simply moved the last SELECT outside of the transaction. I've also added a check for other such cases (code in my answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a little wrapper method that tries to execute a trivial statement as part of the transaction right before committing, which is effective in detecting the problem.

```
    public static void CommitTransaction(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTransaction tran)
    {
        using (var command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT 1", conn, tran))
        {
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (NpgsqlException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Code == "25P02")
                    throw new Exception("The transaction is invalid...");
                throw;
            }
        }

        tran.Commit();
    }
```

The fix is either of *Morg.*'s or *Ryan Culpepper*'s answers: either run the statement outside of the transaction or create a SAVEPOINT beforehand and ROLLBACK to it on error.

Answer (score -1):

Having something fail within a transaction and yet the transaction complete wouldn't be very transactional right ?

So basically, if it may fail and you don't care about it, don't put it in the transaction with that which must not fail.

Use transactions as they're meant to be used and you won't have any issues ;)

Comment: It is completely legitimate for the client application (and not ADO.NET provider) to decode whether failure warrants a full roll-back or not. This is a matter of domain-specific knowledge and the client application is only one that has that knowledge.

Comment: Which is why you use transactions properly, with save points and all.

Comment: But Seriously, your comment is not valid here. A transaction is to be used as a transaction, not as a "package of queries" in which you put random unrelated stuff. It's A TRANSACTION, THE PURPOSE IS TO PACKAGE TOGETHER THINGS THAT HAVE TO BE TOGETHER AND CANNOT EXIST OTHERWISE.  There is no legitimacy in ANY application requesting to package a not-important select in the same transaction as a very-important insert/update.

Comment: I think you are missing the point @Morg: Failure of an SQL statement may not necessarily represent the failure of your application logic (and require a rollback). For example, in a concurrent environment, you may legitimately expect that an INSERT on a table with natural primary key (not auto-increment PK) may fail due other user's action and be fully prepared to retry the INSERT (with a different PK) without rolling back the transaction. BTW save points (or sub-transactions) may not be available on a particular DBMS.

Comment: Regarding your comment: *"There is no legitimacy in ANY application requesting to package a not-important select in the same transaction as a very-important insert/update."* - This actually **may** be legitimate depending on your transaction isolation level (i.e. "Serializable").

Comment: A DBMS without savepoints is also a DBMS where Transaction support is incomplete, we're talking about the best RDBMS possible out here (PostgreSQL) so that is a non-issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3725/discussion-between-morg-and-branko-dimitrijevic)

Comment: Still, the principle of a transaction is that either everything within succeeds or everything within fails. There is nothing legitimate in asking a transaction to succeed if a part of it has failed. It's the meaning of a transaction and if you do not want that behaviour, you do not ask for a transaction - that simple.

Comment: In theory, I agree with you. In practice, the statement that failed was a SELECT and I never expected it to have the effect of aborting the transaction. The real problem, though, is that COMMIT fails *silently* - it appears to work, but commits nothing!